Forward stepwise linear regression using R
I´m running a stepwise forward regression with R but I don´t get any ontput how the model evolve step by step. I´m looking for an output presenting (step by step) how the model grow from 1 predictor til it stops growing.
The syntax I´m using is:
# Initialize model
forward_model <- lm(NPS ~ ., data = SAMBANDSANALYSER)

# Forward stepwise regression
forward_model <- step(forward_model, direction = "forward", scope = formula(~ .))

And I´m looking for a outcome looking like this. This is the steps for at backward regression.


For forward step, you start with a null model:
lm1 <- lm(Fertility ~ 1, data = swiss)
slm1 <- step(lm1, direction="forward", scope=formula(lm(Fertility ~ ., data = swiss)))

Start:  AIC=238.35
Fertility ~ 1

                   Df Sum of Sq    RSS    AIC
+ Education         1    3162.7 4015.2 213.04
+ Examination       1    2994.4 4183.6 214.97
+ Catholic          1    1543.3 5634.7 228.97
+ Infant.Mortality  1    1245.5 5932.4 231.39
+ Agriculture       1     894.8 6283.1 234.09
<none>                          7178.0 238.34

Step:  AIC=213.04
Fertility ~ Education

                   Df Sum of Sq    RSS    AIC
+ Catholic          1    961.07 3054.2 202.18
+ Infant.Mortality  1    891.25 3124.0 203.25
+ Examination       1    465.63 3549.6 209.25
<none>                          4015.2 213.04
+ Agriculture       1     61.97 3953.3 214.31
...

